# JSON - Why I got null object when not using JSON.stringify?

Tags: json

I'm using bootstrap 3 and jquery to develop my app. My question is, why i got null object if not using JSON.stringify instead formValues?

Before using JSON.stringify

```
var that = this;
var formValues = {
    userId: 315,
    locale: "en",
};
this.collection.fetch({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: formValues,
    success: function(collection, response) {
        var template = _.template(accountsSummaryTemplate, {
            accounts: that.collection.models
        });
        that.$el.html(template);
        console.log(that.collection);
    },
    error: function(collection, response) {
        console.log(that.collection);
    }
});
```

After using JSON.stringify

var that = this;

```
function formToJSON() {
return JSON.stringify({
    "userId": 315,
    "locale": "en",
});
}
this.collection.fetch({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: formToJSON(),
    success: function(collection, response) {
        var template = _.template(accountsSummaryTemplate, {
            accounts: that.collection.models
        });
        that.$el.html(template);
        console.log(that.collection);
    },
    error: function(collection, response) {
        console.log(that.collection);
    }
});
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `data` property is an object, jQuery serializes it with `$.param`:

```
> $.param({userId: 315, locale: "en"});
"userId=315&locale=en"
```

If you pass in a string instead, jQuery doesn't serialize it. Look at the requests using your web browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's not a proper data string.

```
 var formValues = "userid=5&locale=en";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because JS object is not JSON. JSON is string, JS object is an object. If `fetch` uses `jQuery.ajax`, it expects either a JS object, or a query string (which is *not* JSON): `"userId=315&locale=en"`.